# Timestamp and Date recording

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop, excel-formula

I have a problem I have been trying to solve. I am trying to build a macro  whereby  when certain cells (E5,E8,E10,E12) are updated in Sheet1 and file is also saved ( both criterias to be met), I want a timestamp to be created in sheet(“Dates”) with username (Environ("Username"))  column A , Date in column B and Time in column C.

**Part 2 of my problem.**
When the cells in sheet1 are later updated. I need the information in sheet(“Dates”) updated with a new additional line ,but if this new date occurs in the same week as the dates already there, it should update that row. So I am trying to avoid dates in the same week being saved. The **objective** is to record when the tasks were last done for each week.

I had started here.

```
Function LastSavedTimeStamp()
 LastSavedTimeStamp = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function

=IF((WEEKNUM(A2,2)=WEEKNUM(B2,2)),"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Put all of this in `ThisWorkbook`

```
'set as public variables to remain saved while workbook is open
Public val1, val2, val3, val4

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'set the variables when the workbook is opened
Call SetValues
End Sub

Private Sub SetValues()
'save the values to be checked later
val1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E5").Value
val2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E8").Value
val3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E10").Value
val4 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E12").Value
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDates As Worksheet
Dim endRow As Long, updateRow As Long, x As Long
Dim checkDate

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDates = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dates")

'if the values have been changed
If _
val1 <> ws.Range("E5").Value Or _
val2 <> ws.Range("E8").Value Or _
val3 <> ws.Range("E10").Value Or _
val4 <> ws.Range("E12").Value Then

    'reset the values to avoid multiple updates
    Call SetValues

    'set the range of values to check
    endRow = wsDates.Cells(wsDates.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'check to see if an entry was found the same week
    For x = 1 To endRow
        checkDate = wsDates.Cells(x, 2).Value
        If checkDate >= (Date - Weekday(Date, vbSunday) + 1) And checkDate <= (Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday) + 1 + 7) Then
            updateRow = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    'if an entry the same week wasn't found, set update row to new row
    If updateRow = 0 Then updateRow = endRow + 1

    'update or add information
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 1).Formula = Environ("Username")
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 2).Formula = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 3).Formula = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")

End If

End Sub
```

It's a little hard to test as far as possibility of a different week is concerned, but I think it should work.

**EDIT**: This version handles a much larger number of individual cells to check by using a couple arrays. As before, put it in `ThisWorkbook` and you should be good.

```
'set as global variables to remain saved while workbook is open
Option Explicit
Private val() As Variant, rng() As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'define which cells to check
rng = Array("D20", "D24", "D25", "D27", "D28", "D30", "D31", "D32", "D33", "D34", "D35", "D37", "D38", "D40", "D42", "D43", "D44", "D54", "D55", "D56", "D58", "D59", "D61", "D62", "D63", "D64", "D65", "E20", "E24", "E25", "E27", "E28", "E30", "E31", "E32", "E33", "E34", "E35", "E37", "E38", "E40", "E42", "E43", "E44", "E54", "E55", "E56", "E58", "E59", "E61", "E62", "E63", "E64", "E65")

'redefine the val array to match the size of the rng array (necessary)
ReDim val(53) As Variant

'set the variables when the workbook is opened
Call SetValues
End Sub

Private Sub SetValues()
Dim x As Long
'save the values to be checked later
For x = LBound(rng()) To UBound(rng())
    val(x) = Sheets("Sheet3").Range(rng(x)).Value
Next x
End Sub

Private Function ValuesChanged() As Boolean
Dim x As Long
'check the values
For x = LBound(rng()) To UBound(rng())
    If val(x) <> Sheets("Sheet3").Range(rng(x)).Value Then
        ValuesChanged = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next x
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsDates As Worksheet
Dim endRow As Long, updateRow As Long, x As Long
Dim checkDate

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
Set wsDates = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dates")

'if the values have been changed
If ValuesChanged Then

    'reset the values to avoid multiple updates
    Call SetValues

    'set the range of values to check
    endRow = wsDates.Cells(wsDates.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'check to see if an entry was found the same week
    For x = 1 To endRow
        checkDate = wsDates.Cells(x, 2).Value
        If checkDate >= (Date - Weekday(Date, vbSunday) + 1) And checkDate <= (Date - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday) + 1 + 7) Then
            updateRow = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    'if an entry the same week wasn't found, set update row to new row
    If updateRow = 0 Then updateRow = endRow + 1

    'update or add information
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 1).Formula = Environ("Username")
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 2).Formula = Format(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    wsDates.Cells(updateRow, 3).Formula = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very very much

Comment: @JFox Just a quick question. I want to expand my range to Sheet3.Range E ( 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65)   Sheet3.Range D ( 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65)  I have been working on this and i have had no success.

Comment: @James The simplest way would be just to make a ton more variables, but I made a much more compact version that uses a couple arrays (I added it to the answer above below the original answer).